# Laravel - Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I am importing some content from remote WP database to local DB with laravel. I have set up the tables inventories and contents.

Inventories table looks like this:

```
    Schema::create('inventories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('remote_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('local_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('local_type');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('local_id')->references('id')->on('contents')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

This is the contents table:

```
    Schema::create('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('ct_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('ct_id')->references('id')->on('content_types');
        $table->integer('cms_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->text('excerpt');
        $table->mediumText('body');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('parent_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have made functions to import all and import single posts from remote WP DB. This is the import for all posts:

```
public function all()
{
    $include      = array_diff($this->indexable, ['folder']);
    $publishedPostsIDs = $this->import($include);
    $this->deleteOldContent($publishedPostsIDs);
}

private function import($include)
{
    $posts             = Post::where('post_status', 'publish')->whereIn('post_type', $include)->get();
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $publishedPostsIDs[] = $post->ID;
        $this->contentInterface->updateOrCreateInventory($post->ID);
    }

    return $publishedPostsIDs;
}

public function updateOrCreateInventory($remoteId)
{
    $this->contentInterface->updateOrCreateInventory($remoteId);
}

private function deleteOldContent($publishedPostsIDs)
{
    $contentToDelete = Content::whereNotIn('cms_id', $publishedPostsIDs)->get();

    if (count($contentToDelete) > 0) {
        foreach ($contentToDelete as $content) {
            $content->delete();
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I am importing all, I just go to the route that goes to `all` function, and all the posts from remote WP DB that are not of post type folder are imported. If I want to import a single post from remote DB, then I have a route that goes directly to the `updateOrCreateInventory` function. I also have import for the posts of type folder, which is basically almost the same as the function `all`.

```
public function folder()
{
    $include = ['folder'];
    $importResult = $this->import($include);

    return $importResult['imported'];
}
```

The problem I have is that when I am importing all folders at once I get an error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 729: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`middleton`.`inventories`, CONSTRAINT
>   `inventories_local_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`local_id`) REFERENCES
>   `contents` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `inventories`
>   (`remote_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (7512, 2017-11-13
>   15:33:17, 2017-11-13 15:33:17))

But, if I try to import that same folder individually , or to be more exact that same post of type folder, I don't get any error and the post is imported. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You $this->contentInterface creates an Inventory model without the "local_id" field specified, but it is required by the foreign key.

Find the place where you create the Inventory model and provide a valid "local_id".